# Android Studio - Can not open device monitor

Tags: android, android-studio, device, monitor

I just downloaded Android Studio and it seems to import my existing Eclipse project well.

However, if I try to open "Android Device Monitor" I get the message "An error has occurred" with a reference to a log file.

My log file is included underneath. I am not sure why there is a reference to "Eclipse" int it? Anyhow, all in all, I have no idea where to go from here

> !SESSION 2015-01-05 04:00:15.329
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.8.0_25 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
>   NL=en_US Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
>   -data @noDefault
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:15.930 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:15.934 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4
>   not found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:15.935 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not
>   found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:15.975 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not
>   found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:15.975 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not
>   found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:15.975 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4
>   not found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:15.977 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not
>   found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:15.981 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4
>   not found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:16.009 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not
>   found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:16.009 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not
>   found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:16.010 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4
>   not found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:16.013 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not
>   found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE One or
>   more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints
>   are not resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05
>   04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry
>   2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE Missing required capability
>   Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
>   filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.340 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-01-05
>   04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability:
>   osgi.ee;
>   filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-01-05
>   04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524/
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Missing required capability
>   Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
>   filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05
>   04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Missing
>   imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE Missing
>   imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.342 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.398 !MESSAGE The
>   following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see
>   the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists: !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.398 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721 [25] was not resolved. !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.398 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE Missing
>   optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE
>   Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.apache.lucene.highlighter_[2.9.1,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE Missing
>   optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.memory_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE
>   Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.apache.lucene.queries_[2.9.1,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene
>   2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE Missing optionally required
>   bundle org.apache.lucene.snowball_[2.9.1,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE Missing
>   optionally required bundle
>   org.apache.lucene.spellchecker_[2.9.1,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.apache.lucene 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE Missing
>   optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.misc_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721 [26] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2015-01-05
>   04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239 [90] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05
>   04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.399
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_[8.0.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548 [93] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2015-01-05
>   04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
>   filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548 [94]
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry
>   2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400
>   !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
>   filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522 [137] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2015-01-05
>   04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE
>   Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522 [138] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.jmx_8.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Missing
>   imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Missing
>   imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Missing
>   imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543 [146] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2015-01-05
>   04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.400 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200 [149] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE Missing
>   optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
>   filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.search_3.8.0.v20120523-1540 [151] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524 [163]
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.400.v20120705-114010 [165] was
>   not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0
>   2015-01-05 04:00:17.401 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-05 04:00:17.403 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.io.IOException: The folder
>   "C:\Users\My%20Example%Name.android\monitor-workspace.metadata" is
>   read-only.    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.lock(BasicLocation.java:206)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:164)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:137)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

Answer (score 3):

The solution posted in the following [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72610) worked for me. I added the answer below, but you can take a look at the link for more information. Also, I am using Windows 8 and it worked as well.

This is what I had to do to resolve it in Windows 7 64  bit:

1. Run the task manager
2. End the process for monitor
3. Also end the java processes.  Just doing monitor won't do the trick.
4. Relaunch the monitor.  Now it runs.

Comment: Same issue and resolved with this - Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

1. Install JRE into *C:\Java\jre* folder.
2. Copy **monitor-x86_64** folder from *C:\Users\User%Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib* to *C:\Java*.
3. Copy jre folder from *C:\Java\jre* to *C:\Java\monitor-x86_64\jre*.
4. Set PATH *C:\Java\monitor-x86_64\jre\bin*.
5. Run *C:\Java\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe* as administrator.
6. PROFIT!

**ENV**:
Android Studio 4.1.3
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119, built on March 11, 2021
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

win10 x64 - i had java 9.0.1, android device monitor was crashing all the time.

then i removed this java version from system and installed java 8 (u151), it helped

if you have multiple java installations - check the PATH variable, the monitor looks up for javaw.exe file, and if it's version doesnt work with monitor - it crashes

Answer (score 0):

alternatively simple :

1.do several times

taskkill /IM monitor.exe

until one process remains and "can never be killed".

2.open task manager

find the monitor and expand it with PLUS + sign

you will find a message with a fail or similar

right click and select "kill"

3. then, immediately monitor GUI will appear on your screen, as if something was preventing it to be visible.