# Android device manager is not opening and showing an error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, sdk, android-device-monitor

Android device manager is not opening and showing an error to check log files in sdk ..in android device manager , ubuntu 15.10

```
java.version=1.8.0_76-release
java.vendor=JetBrains s.r.o
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.067
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.070
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.071
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.111
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.115
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.116
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.117
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.121
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.127
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.130
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.132
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:37.133
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-11-05 16:57:38.034
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor (5).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin for bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor is invalid
```

Comment: have you tried : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772898/android-studio-can-not-open-device-monitor

Comment: Shorter title. Error description in the question. Format the error log